# How do I get the value of a child on clicking another child of a parent Class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

consider I have such a structure(a group of fields which repeat);

```
 <div class="form-group Row"> <!-- first row-->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control User" name="user" value="$users" placeholder="Username" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pw" value="$passwords" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>
    <a class="delete" onclick='//do something'><img src="delete.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="form-group Row"><!-- second row-->
    <div class="col-sm-3"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control User" name="user" value="$user" placeholder="Username" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pw" value="$passwords" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>
    <a class="delete" onclick='//do something'><img src="delete.png"></a>
</div>
```

when I click on the delete-image of any Row, I want to get the value of the input field with class name "User" of this specific Row. 
How can I do this in javascript?

Comment: @  taxicala  and Federico thank you! Your answers were also correct.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery you don't need use inline events, you can add events with `.on` function, and get value like in example

```
$('.delete').on('click', function () {
   var value = $(this).parent().find('.User').val();
   console.log(value)
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/hoquqo/1/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows:

```
$('.delete').on('click', function(){
    var value = $(this).closest('.row').find('.User').val();
    //Do something with value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS your "do something" will be like this:

```
alert( this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("user")[0].value; )
```